# Is there a fast version of DataBinder.Eval for C#?

Tags: c#, compilation, eval, expression

I'm looking to see if a fast version of ASP.NET's System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval() exists? 
Ideally something that compiles to a Func that I can cache and call later, like:

```
Func<object,string> expr = CompileDataBinder(typeof(Model), "model.PocoProperty.Name");
string propertyName = expr(model);
```

Does anyone know if such a beast exists?

P.S. I'm not using ASP.NET and would like it to work in normal C#

Comment: Are you currently encountering some performance problems due to the classic `Eval` method? If, yes, could you explain your scenario, show the code you are using, comment on the results you obtained when performed load tests that lead you to this conclusion? If not why do you need this?

Comment: Because I actually care about performance and don't want to include inefficient execution paths in my compiled templates.

Comment: @mythz, `Eval` is not inefficient. Many heavy traffic sites are using it.

Comment: I can do without the efficiency of something is 300x slower than the equivalent strongly typed cast + property access.

Comment: @Darin: Does `Eval` use reflection?

Comment: @Darin your 1st comment is frustratingly typical of the inertia I face everyday typical when dealing with the .NET culture. As a member of a many NoSQL forums I can say this doesn't happen on any other platform  where I have to prove why I would want to maintain high-perf systems. I'm surprised at 172k you're a long-time SO user who is oblivious as to what one of the major reasons that makes SO so enjoyable to use (http://goo.gl/G85eh http://goo.gl/fm9Zl). I've tried articulating why its so important https://github.com/mythz/ScalingDotNET but falls on deaf ears, your upvote is typical and sad.

Comment: Anyway the whole rationale behind my rant is trying to try to get other .NET devs to please hold your comments that serve to prevent others in their pursuit of max perf and end user UX. I personally think this attitude creates stigma and hurts .NET as a whole. .NET is behind other platforms in this regard and we need all the help we can get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more I look at it, the more I want to say:

```
Func<Model,string> expr = model => model.PocoProperty.Name;
```

if you need it based on a string, the `Expression` API is pretty fair there.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<object, string> expr = CompileDataBinder(typeof(Model), "PocoProperty.Name");

        var model = new Model { PocoProperty = new ModelPoco { Name = "Foo" } };

        string propertyName = expr(model);
    }
    static Func<object, string> CompileDataBinder(Type type, string expr)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        Expression body = Expression.Convert(param, type);
        var members = expr.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < members.Length;i++ )
        {
            body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, members[i]);
        }
        var method = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null, new Type[] { body.Type }, null);
        if (method == null)
        {
            method = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, new Type[] { typeof(object)}, null);
            body = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object)));
        }
        else
        {
            body = Expression.Call(method, body);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(body, param).Compile();
    }
}

class Model
{
    public ModelPoco PocoProperty { get; set; }
}
class ModelPoco
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Unfortunately the string is only known at runtime.

Comment: @mythz - note I tightened the code a bit to handle some edge-cases

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that should get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;


class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FullName FullName { get; set; }
}

class FullName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person model = new Person
        {
            Id = 123,
            FullName = new FullName
            {
                FirstName = "Duncan",
                LastName = "Smart",
            }
        };

        var nameBinder = CompileDataBinder<Person, string>("model.FullName.FirstName");
        string fname = nameBinder(model);
        Debug.Assert(fname == "Duncan");

        // Note how here we pretend we don't know TProp type
        var idBinder = CompileDataBinder<Person, object>("model.Id");
        object id = idBinder(model);
        Debug.Assert(id.Equals(123));
    }

    static Func<TModel, TProp> CompileDataBinder<TModel, TProp>(string expression)
    {
        var propNames = expression.Split('.');

        var model = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "model");

        Expression body = model;
        foreach (string propName in propNames.Skip(1))
            body = Expression.Property(body, propName);
        //Debug.WriteLine(prop);

        if (body.Type != typeof(TProp))
            body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(TProp));

        Func<TModel, TProp> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProp>>(body, model).Compile();
        //TODO: cache funcs
        return func;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game, but this was my solution.

I added this private method to a string Extension class called [FormatWith](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables) Removing the DataBinder reference in favor for this method.

```
#nullable enable
        private static object? Eval(object source, string valueName)
        {
            MemberInfo[] miList = source.GetType().GetMember(valueName);
            foreach (var mi in miList)
            {
                if (mi is PropertyInfo)
                {

                    PropertyInfo? pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                    if (pi != null && pi.CanRead)
                    {
                        return pi.GetValue(source);
                    }
                }
                else if (mi is FieldInfo)
                {
                    FieldInfo? fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                    if (fi != null)
                    {
                        return fi.GetValue(source);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
#nullable disable
```